# Number of ways to write n as a sum of k numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, sum, formula, partitioning

So I have this formula:

```
P(n, 1) = P(n, n) = 1

P(n + k, k) = P(n, 1) + P(n, 2) + ... + P(n, k)
```

But I do not understand it.

Did I write something wrong?
I do not understand why there is "`n+k`" in `P(n + k, k)`

Let's say that P is a function and I call `P(6, 2)`. What does `P(n + k, k)` does? Will it transfrom to `P(8, 2)` or `P(4 + 2, 2)`...

I do not understand how it works, maybe if someone gives me an example, step by step...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math question, not a coding question

Comment: Yeah, and that is why there are no coding related tags

Comment: @MisterBabu.: What is the question? Ask specific question,

Comment: Edited, I hope it is clear now

Comment: I think this should be on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two formula lines are a mathematical definition, not a programming algorithm. And hopefully they provide enough information so that you can find out the value for any `P(x,y)`.

As the first line effectively defines two different cases, I'd like to rewrite the formulas:

```
(A) P(n, 1) = 1

(B) P(n, n) = 1

(C) P(n + k, k) = P(n, 1) + P(n, 2) + ... + P(n, k)
```

So, if you want to apply them to `P(6,2)` then only `(C)` can match, as `(A)` only matches to things like `P(6,1)`, and `(B)` to things like `P(6,6)`.

The match of `P(6,2)` against `P(n+k,k)` means that `k` must be `2`, and `n+k` must be `6`, giving `n=4`.

Then the right-hand side of `(C)` expands to `P(4,1) + P(4,2)`. Its first part matches against `(A)`, and the second one against `(C)`. So, the first part gives `1`, and the second has to be expanded the same way as `P(6,2)`. And so on...

If you were to implement a function computing `P(x,y)` values, the straightforward way would be to transform the definition formulas to a recursive computation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to apply formulas *again and again*:

```
   P(6, 2) = P(4 + 2, 2) = P(4, 1) + P(4, 2)
```

Now for `P(4, 1)` we have

```
   P(4, 1) = P(3 + 1, 1) = P(3, 1) = P(2 + 1, 1) = P(2, 1) = P(1 + 1, 1) = P(1, 1) = 1
```

With a help of *induction* we can prove that `P(N, 1) = 1` when `N >= 1`

For `P(4, 2)` we have

```
   P(4, 2) = P(2 + 2, 2) = P(2, 2) + P(2, 1) = 1 + P(2, 1) = 
           = 1 + P(1 + 1, 1) = 1 + P(1, 1) = 1 + 1 = 2
```

Finally

```
   P(6, 2) = P(4 + 2, 2) = P(4, 1) + P(4, 2) = 1 + 2 = 3
```

In general case (again *induction*) `P(2 * N, 2) = N`

Simplest **C#** implementation (doesn't work for some inputs like, say `P(0, 1)`):

```
private static Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int> s_Cached = 
  new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>();

private static int P(int n, int k) {
  if (n == k)
    return 1;

  if (s_Cached.TryGetValue(new Tuple<int, int>(n, k), out var value))
    return value;

  int result = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
    result += P(n - k, i);

  s_Cached.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(n, k), result);

  return result;
}
```

Test

```
Console.WriteLine(P(6, 2));
```